# wav files play error on Jessie

Tags: audio-playback

Newbe here trying to learn Linux on Raspberry Pi 2B Jessie. While I can get the Front Center wave file to play with:

```
sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

When I try to play my wave files I get one of two errors:

No such file or directory, or file not found, even though I am in the folder where the wave file resides and have verified with ls as well as verifying the path as `/home/pi`.
The service pulseaudio status results are:

```
pulseaudio.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I just want to play the wave files in my folder continuously in a loop.

I installed mplayer when aplayer produced those errors. No change. What am I missing? Trying to associate the player to the .wave files was unsuccessful as well. This is sure different from Windows where I could do this in 10 seconds!

```
ls-la /home/pi

total 222220

drwxr-xr-x 23 pi   pi        4096 Apr 23 05:08 .

drwxr-xr-x  3 root root      4096 Sep 24  2015 ..

-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi    26460046 Feb 12 18:20 test 1.wav

-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi    26460046 Feb 12 18:23 test 2.wav

-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi    26460046 Apr 22 11:36 test 3.wav

-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi    26460046 Oct 12  2015 test 4.wav
```

etc.

So researching file permissions I see these files as well as all files copied from a jump drive cannot be read. Does this mean all file permissions will have to be changed once copied onto the Pi? This also explains why the programs would not install. Is there a way to copy files and retain their permissions?

Comment: What is the output of ls -la /home/pi?

Comment: Try removing the space in the name. mv "test 1.wav" test_1.wav spaces make things harder on Linux and should be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

Try converting to MP4 they work. Use a site like clipconverter.cc then try again!!
Try removing the space in the name. mv "test 1.wav" test_1.wav spaces make things harder on Linux and should be avoided.

Comment: If the wav player worked in his test why wouldn't they work with his own wav files.

Comment: @SteveRobillard not sure but try converting them,

Comment: If you look at his file names I would bet dollars to donuts the problem is the space in the file name. Which isn't a guess and explains why the test works but his files don't.

Comment: @SteveRobillard you have a point

Comment: Turns out it was the file permissions. Once I changed that parameter and took out the space the file played. Sure wish there was a "Pitfalls for Linux Newbes" out there. I still have not figured out how to associate the file to open with a program though, but that's a separate Java problem.

Comment: @GranDy It was not a file permission issue, it's an argument issue. Bash (the program that handles most terminal interactions on linux systems) has a very strict format (which is a good thing). It's a program to run follow by a *space separated* list of arguments. So, if you type `aplay my file.wav`, bash runs the program `aplay` with two arguments: `my` and `file.wav`. `aplay` assumes that each argument is a file and thus cannot find them. Tell bash that your single argument has a space in it: `aplay "my file.wav"` or `aplay my\ file.wav`.